# Apache Kafka and Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, reactive-programming, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm reading through this blog post:

http://blog.jaceklaskowski.pl/2015/07/20/real-time-data-processing-using-apache-kafka-and-spark-streaming.html

It discusses about using Spark Streaming and Apache Kafka to do some near real time processing. I completely understand the article. It does show how I could use Spark Streaming to read messages from a Topic. I would like to know if there is a Spark Streaming API that I can use to write messages into Kakfa topic?

My use case is pretty simple. I have a set of data that I can read from a given source at a constant interval (say every second). I do this using reactive streams. I would like to do some analytics on this data using Spark. I want to have fault-tolerance, so Kafka comes into play. So what I would essentially do is the following (Please correct me if I was wrong):

1. Using reactive streams get the data from external source at constant intervals
2. Pipe the result into Kafka topic
3. Using Spark Streaming, create the streaming context for the consumer
4. Perform analytics on the consumed data

One another question though, is the Streaming API in Spark an implementation of the reactive streams specification? Does it have back pressure handling (Spark Streaming v1.5)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, at the moment, none of Spark Streaming's built-in receiver APIs are an implementation of the Reactive Streams implementation. But there's an [issue for that](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10420) you will want to follow.
2. But Spark Streaming 1.5 [has internal back-pressure-based dynamic throttling](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/09/announcing-spark-1-5.html). There's some [work to extend that beyond throttling](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8835) in the pipeline. This throttling is compatible with the Kafka direct stream API.
3. You can write to Kafka in a Spark Streaming application, here's [one example](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/#writing-to-kafka).

(Full disclosure: I'm one of the [implementers](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/798dff7b4baa952c609725b852bcb6a9c9e5a317) of some of the back-pressure work)

Comment: I have a question about backpressure feature to you as an implementor:
I'm enabling backpressure, but have no impact to the system. I'm processing rather big data items with the throughput of around 40 items/sec from my source. I fixed already the maxRate as otherwise the delay times continue growing and never stop. Backpressure seemed to work with processing tweets where the data rate is about 15000 tweets/sec...

Answer (score 0):

If you have to write the results stream to another Kafka topic let say 'topic_x', First, you must have columns by the name 'Key' and 'Value' in the result stream which you are trying to write to the topic_x.

```
result_stream = result_stream.selectExpr('CAST (key AS STRING)','CAST (value AS STRING)')
kafkaOutput = result_stream \
               .writeStream \
               .format('kafka') \
               .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers','192.X.X.X:9092') \
               .option('topic','topic_x') \
               .option('checkpointLocation','./resultCheckpoint') \
               .start()

kafkaOutput.awaitTermination()
```

For more details check the documentation at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html